# Angular 4 GET Request (Observable)

Tags: angular, canactivate

I'm trying to get an observable in Angular 4 project\
The get request is okay but I'm getting pushed away to 403 unauthorized page while I'm the admin,
I'm trying to understand the problem of this, I debugged the code but I cant get it, The code run perfectly fine but I'm getting pushed to 403 anyway...

```
   isAdmin(): Observable<object> {
        if (!this._isAdmin) {
            this._isAdmin = this.http.get('./api/account/admin')
            .map(
        (res: Response) => res.json())
        .publishReplay(1)
        .refCount()
        .catch((error: any) => {
            this.router.navigate(['/error/403']);
            return Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error');
        })      
    }
        if (!this._isAdmin) {
            this.router.navigate(['/error/403']);
            return Observable.throw('Server error');
        }        
        return this._isAdmin;
    }



   canActivate(
     next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
     state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {             
         console.log("check");
     const allowedRoles = next.data.permittedRoles as Array<string>;

        this.authService.isAdmin().subscribe(
            (data: any) => {
            if (!data) {
                this.router.navigate(['/error/403']);
                return false;
            }
            allowedRoles.forEach((element: any) => {
                if (data.RoleType === element) {         
         if (data.IsAdmin) {
                return true;
            }         
        }
    }),
    (err: any) =>         
    {
        console.log(err);
        this.router.navigate(['/error/403']);
        return false;
}});
this.router.navigate(['/error/403']);
       return false;
}
}
```

Comment: Try to use pipable operators in your isAdmin method. And in Angular 4 you get json, you don't need `res.json()`

Comment: Need to remove res.json()? to this =>  .map(
        (res: Response))
        .publishReplay(1)
        .refCount() @igor_c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after some months I wasn't aware of this but my IIS Authentication was Anonymous & Windows authentication, I had to remove the Anonymous Authentication in order it to work

Answer (score -1):

You need to return an observable from your guard, since you cannot return from `subscribe`. Also if you are using `HttpClient`, that I hope you do, you don't need to parse to JSON, as the `HttpClient` does that for you. **If** you are using `Http`, I strongly suggest you move on to using `HttpClient`. Anyway, assuming you are using HttpClient,  your code should looks something like this:

```ts
isAdmin(): Observable<object> {
  return this.http.get('./api/account/admin')
}
```

and the guard (which I slightly modified from Norbert's answer by changing `subscribe` to `map`):

```ts
canActivate(next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> {
  this.authService.isAdmin().map((data) => {
    if (data && data.isAdmin) {
      return true;
    }
    this.router.navigate(['/error/403']);
    return false;
  }
}
```

I omitted the `forEach` loop, since I didn't see how it would fit in here, since you are anyway checking if `data.isAdmin` exists. But if you for some reason need it, I would suggest a for loop, forEach cannot return anything. Also you need to assign the truthy or falsy value to variable, since in a for loop `return` just breaks the loop.

```ts
let bool = false;
for(let element of allowedRoles) {
  if (data.RoleType === element) {
    if (data.IsAdmin) {
      bool = true;
      return;
    } 
  }
}

if (bool) { return true }
```

Comment: If you set the return type of `canActivate` to `boolean` or `UrlTree` but never return a `UrlTree` then its kinda useless to set it at all. Also you call the method `router.parseUrl(...)` whitch return `UrlTree` and dont use it. Please don't just copy and paste answers.

Comment: @NorbertBartko, eh... from where do I just "copy and paste" answer? This came from my head, but sure, I can remove the `UrlTree`, and I also see another error I made, so thanks for making me look closer at my code.

Comment: @NorbertBartko, aaah, now I perhaps understand what you mean with copying perhaps. Sure, I used your code as base but put my own twist on it. So I did not copy your answer, which would have been a no-no and also no point in then even write up an answer. But excuse me if that offended you. I could of course had copied OP's code and rewrite all of it, but since your answer was closer to mine I ruthlessly used it as a base. Sorry again, I'll be sure to be more respecting in future.